# 2x2x2 plus control group: nested ANOVA?

Tags: anova, experiment-design, nested-data

I recently ran an experiment assessing the impact of three system factors (factor A; factor B; factor C) on user attitudes (4-item scale). Each system factor had two levels (high vs. low). As a result, my experiment had nine conditions: eight treatment conditions (reflecting the 2x2x2 design) plus one control group. Subjects in the control group used a "baseline" system in which none of the three system factors were present.

To analyze my data, I am considering to run two ANOVAs: (1) a one-way ANOVA comparing the control group with the overall treatment average and (2) a 2x2x2 ANOVA comparing the three factors and their interactions. However, this would not allow me to simultaneously compare the three factors with the control group.

How could this be done? A nested ANOVA? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the technique detailed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372257/how-do-you-deal-with-nested-variables-in-a-regression-model/372258#372258  might help?